# Is it bad to have 2 keys for identifying a valid information?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

> Is it a bad ideea to have 2 keys for identifying a valid information ?

Company information table serves the car wash table and also the car service table

Let's say We have a table that has the categories

=== Category Table ===

```
id
category_name
active
position
path
```

Then i have the table that serves the two different tables.

==== Company Information ====

```
id
parent_id
category_id
company_name
company_adress
bank_name
```

The two tables  that are from different categories

==== Car wash table ===

```
id ( this will be the parent id in company information )
category_id
...other_fields
```

=== Car service table ===

```
id ( this will be the parent id in company information )
category_id
...other_fields
```

Comment: If some of your other_fields are same for both car service and car wash ie car model you may consider having one table called Car  { id, category_id shared_fields } and two other separated tables CarWash { CarID OtherCarWashFields } and CarService { CarID, OtherCasServiceFields }

Comment: The fields that are the same for the car wash table and the car service table are the fields from company information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing fundamentally wrong with having the same same key in one table referenced by multiple foreign keys in other tables. It is quite normal.